# Why am I getting unexpected results with state custom class method in reducer?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, state-management, redux-reducers

I'm getting unexpected state handling in the redux reducer.

If I'm using the following code to handle `selectPackage` action, I'm getting the wrong state when the reducer is done. Upon further inspection, it turns out that the `selectPackage` method in `CartState` is not getting the same object upon which I'm calling the method, instead it's getting some older state (stale, not updated by the last action).

```js
export class CartState {
  item: CartItem

  haveItem = (tourId: string) => {
    const newItem = this.item ? iObject.shallowCloneTypeSafe(this.item) : new CartItem()
    newItem.tourId = tourId
    return iObject.updateKeyImmutably(this, 'item', newItem)
  }

  selectPackage = (packageId: string) => {
    const newItem = iObject.updateKeyImmutably(this.item, 'packageId', packageId)
    return iObject.updateKeyImmutably(this, 'item', newItem)
  }
  static getInitialState = () => new CartState()
}

export const cartReducer: CartReducer = (state = CartState.getInitialState(), action) => {
  let newItem, newState
  switch (action.type) {
    case CartActionType.HaveCartItem:
      return state.haveItem(action.payload.tourId)
    case CartActionType.SelectPackage:
      return state.selectPackage(action.payload.packageId)
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

But if I'm doing exact same thing, but without using the `CartState`'s `selectPackage` method, it works exactly as expected.

```js
export class CartState {
  item: CartItem

  static getInitialState = () => new CartState()
}

export const cartReducer: CartReducer = (state = CartState.getInitialState(), action) => {
  let newItem, newState
  switch (action.type) {
    case CartActionType.HaveCartItem:
      newItem = state.item ? iObject.shallowCloneTypeSafe(state.item) : new CartItem()
      newItem.tourId = action.payload.tourId
      return iObject.updateKeyImmutably(state, 'item', newItem)
    case CartActionType.SelectPackage:
      newItem = iObject.updateKeyImmutably(state.item, 'packageId', action.payload.packageId)
      return iObject.updateKeyImmutably(state, 'item', newItem)
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Just how is that possible? And it's not just this reducer, the same is happening all over the place.
Any helpful hint will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**You should *never* use classes as state in Redux reducers**.  State should always be plain serializable JS values:

- https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions

Also, you *should* be using our official Redux Toolkit package to write your Redux logic. It will drastically simplify your code (even what you've shown here), including letting you write "mutating" syntax for immutable updates in reducers:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux